# Changing an arg in __new__ is not carrying over to __init__

Tags: python

I am having trouble understanding what is happening here, because this is something I thought worked.

```
class Test(object):

    def __new__(cls, arg):
        return object.__new__(cls, 345)

    def __init__(self, arg):
        self.arg = arg

test = Test('testing')
print
print '****', test.arg
```

This little example outlines the confusion I am having. Within the new function I am making it so that I pass an integer of 345 instead of my string of "testing" when creating the class. However, when I check the arg afterwards it is still my string of "testing".

At the same time, this example from the Python docs does work:

```
class inch(float):
    "Convert from inch to meter"
    def __new__(cls, arg=0.0):
        return float.__new__(cls, arg*0.0254)
print inch(12)
```

Can someone explain what the difference is here? Is there some way for me to get the functionality I am looking for?

Comment: Just to be clear you only need to use this technique when subclassing  an immutable type or similar. Otherwise, just use `__init__`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`object.__new__` accepts, but ignores, any arguments other than the first class argument. This allows you to add other arguments to `__new__` in a subclass without breaking calls to `super().__new__`.

`float.__new__` is a separate function which uses its second argument to provide a value.

Comment: I wasn't aware of that. So does the OP need to explicitly call initialise one the new object?

Comment: Very interesting. I wasn't aware that's how it worked. Always thought the arguments provided to new gets passed along to init.

Comment: The argument(s) to `Test.__new__` are passed to the *implicit* call to `Test.__init__`; `object.__init__` is only called if *explicitly* called from `Test.__init__`.